# Attributes are lost in raster after changing extension and resolution in R

Tags: raster, r

I have the following raster:

```
> modis
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1776, 4320, 7672320  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -64, 84  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /Users/maps/MODIS_PANratios.tif 
names       : MODIS_PANratios 
values      : 1, 20  (min, max)
attributes  :
       ID       category
 from:  0               
 to  : 20 Woody savannas
```

Please note this raster contains categorical attributes.

I want to create a raster `stack` with `modis`and a second raster with different resolution and extent:

```
> rDif
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 720, 1440, 1036800  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /Users/maps/liuDif.tif 
names       : liuDif 
values      : 0, 4150641  (min, max)
```

I use `project raster`to adapt extent and resolution from `modis` to `rDif`to be able to stack both:

```
modis.new <- projectRaster(from=modis, to=rDif, method="ngb")
```

The problem is that the new raster has lost its original attributes:

```
> modis.new
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 720, 1440, 1036800  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : MODIS_PANratios 
values      : 1, 20  (min, max)
```

How can I standardise the extent and resolution of two rasters without loosing the original attributes?

Comment: With original attributes, do you mean `dimensions` and `resolution`? Or value 0? Seems that 0 has no class assigned

Comment: Indeed, 0's are missing values, reason there is no class assigned. Is this the reason the category names are lost?

Comment: I think the process lost category names, I'm not sure. You can make a backup as a workaround of this problem `backup <- levels(modis) ; levels(modis.new) <- backup`

Comment: This is off-topic, but how can I convert 0's to NAs? I have tried `modis[modis==0] <- NA` but the 0 class with no name assigned still appears

Comment: The output of `levels(modis)` consider value 0? An option could be erasing it from this list

Answer (score 2):

As you have multiple setting to standardise the easiest option is [spatial_sync_raster](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatial.tools/versions/1.4.8/topics/spatial_sync_raster) from the spatial.tools package.

This will match the extent, resolution, and crs. It does, however, take quite some time. As you have categorical data you need method ="ngb" to set the re sampling to nearest neighbor